# Continuity of $A \in M_n(\mathbb{R}) \mapsto A^k$

Tags: matrices, continuity

How do you prove $A \in M_n(\mathbb{R}) \mapsto A^k$ to be continuous?

Comment: what norm do you have in the domain?

Comment: I'd use \sup{|a_ij|} but aren't they all equivalent ?

Comment: oh yeah good point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all norms are equivalent you just need to prove that a certain function:

$\mathbb R^{n\times n} \rightarrow \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ in which every coordinate (in the codomain) is just a polynomial in terms of all of the variables in the domain.

Comment: Okay, so I could say that if $B = A^k$, $\sup{b_{ij}}$ is a polynomial with the $a_{ij}$ as variables ?

Comment: I would use the euclidean norm in the domain and codomain, and use coordinate-wise continuity and equivalence of norms.

Comment: oh ok yes, that one is easier to work with

Comment: Yeah, and I think most people show in calculus 3 that only coordinate continuity is needed with euclidean norm. And they also prove that polynomials $\mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$ are continuous.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If you consider the coordinates, its components are polynomial functions.